# Python range - Print from desired number till desired number

Tags: python-3.x

Python `range ()` seems to be weird. I want to print the number from 1 to 9, for that I have typed the following code

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print i
```

Is there a way of mentioning the start and end numbers in `range()`. Should I use any other function that can do this for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have given `range` the start and end numbers. The arguments are `range(start, stop, step)`

Comment: yes, i know that, i want to know about any other function that can do this cleanly, in powershell we can do the same like 
foreach ($Slot1 in 1..9)
{
Write-Host " $slot1"
}

Comment: (1) a `:` is missing in line 1 (2) `print(i)` in Python 3 (3)  indentation expected in line 2

Comment: edited, but thats not my question, is there a clean way of calling the desired range instead of starting from 0?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `range(1,10)` doesn't start from 0

Comment: Ok, i want to print 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 , if i use the above said code, range(1,10) the 1 is the start and 10 is for printing 10th number starting from 0. in powershell we can set the range clearly like 1..9 and it prints from 1 till 9 ..i just wanted to know whether there is a cleaner function that can only take 1 till 9 and prints only that

Comment: @Python_newbie See answer below. You are confused about how range works. Hopefully that will clarify

Answer (score 0):

You are making an assumption that `range(1,10)` means that

> 10 is for printing 10th number starting from 0.

in the comments. This isn't how `range()` works.

`range()` takes three arguments, 2 required and 1 optional: 
`range(start, stop, step)`. [(further reading)](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

`start` should be the number you want to start with
`stop` is the number you want to ***stop before***
`step` is the increment range you would like to walk between `start` and `stop`

For instance `range(1,10)` will contain all the numbers from 1-9 (note: not including 10): `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

`range(0,10)` would include 0 to above, while `range(1,11)` would include 10.

`range(1,10,2)` would render `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

As for your desire for a "cleaner" solution; that is a subjective question. A list comprehension like `[i for i in range(1,10)]`, or even your nested code in the question is pretty clean by most people's standards.

Comment: Thanks, anyways i know these.

Comment: You clearly didn't, or else you wouldn't have asked the question. Cheers